# Two consecutive identical calls to echo have different output in Vim function

Tags: recursion, vim, scripting, keymapping

[Original post on Vi and Vim Beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21300/6498), which has had [one interesting answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21304/6498), but not much attention so far. I am sorry for the crossposting and I will ask for the original to be closed/deleted.

Given the following function in the `.vimrc` file,

```
fu! MyFun(count)
  echo a:count
  echo a:count
  if a:count > 0
    normal ,
    call MyFun(a:count - 1)
  endif
endf
```

calling `:call MyFun(3)` generates the following output.

```
3
3
2
2
1
1
0
0
```

However, if I define the mapping `nn , :<C-U>execute "call MyFun(" . v:count . ")"<CR>`, then the call to `:call MyFun(3)` generates

```
3
0
2
0
1
0
0
0
```

I do understand that the mapping of `,` makes the `MyFun` function call itself twice (`if a:count > 0`), however I cannot understand how this can cause a different result of the two successive calls to `echo a:count`.

Comment: [answer to a comment which has just been deleted] Actually no, `a:count` is a valid parameter identifier within a function with parameter `count`, as is the case for `MyFun` (what the actual argument passed to the function is, is irrelevant); please check `:h a:var`. `v:count`, on the other hand, is used to retrieve the count given for the last Normal mode command; please, refer to `:h v:count`.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to avoid cross-posting and delete this question? I could re-write my answer for vim.se then.

Comment: Well, I agree with you that the most appropriate site for this question is [https://vi.stackexchange.com/](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) and not StackOverflow. However if had not cross-posted, I wouldn't have received any attention. Since you are available for posting the aswer there, than please do it, and I will close this one. However, in the future, I think that I will post "hardcore" questions here, since there's no much attention there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is all about screen redraw (see `:h echo-redraw`) in Vim.

Changing `echo` to `echom` still produces the same (broken) screen output (`3 0 2 0 1 0 0 0`), but `:mess` reveals what is hidden: `3 3 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0`.

Comment: The last output triggered by `:mess` is indeed the output that a commenter to the [original question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21300/6498) expects.